# Why does Firefox dev tools think getter function from Vue.js object is undefined?

Tags: vue.js, firefox-developer-tools

I have a JavaScript object with some simple properties:

```
class Car {
  constructor(make, model, gasLeft){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.gasLeft = gasLeft;
  }
}

var myCar = new Car("Honda", "Accord", 0);
```

After connecting this to a Vue instance, I can open up the Google Chrome dev tools and call `myCar.make` and see "Honda" or `myCar.gasLeft` and see 0.
I can also just type `myCar` and see all of its properties listed.
However, in Firefox's dev tools, just typing `myCar` and clicking "invoke getter" for gasLeft shows gasLeft as `"undefined"`. But when I type `myCar.gasLeft` it does return 0.

If I understand correctly, Vue.js adds getters to the properties it can, so I'm actually calling the `get gasLeft()` function behind the scenes. But why does Firefox return `undefined` and Chrome returns 0? Also, the Vue dev tool extension in both browsers know the `gasLeft` value is 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "after connecting this to a Vue instance"?

Comment: So I have my `myCar` object. In the `window.onload` function, I do `new Vue({el: "#main", data: {car: myCar}})`, basically getting the object wired up with a Vue object. Vue changes any properties in the `myCar` object to have getters and setters, rather than just standard properties.